# Test startActivity with implicit Intent failure

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-intent, mockito, android-espresso

I'm trying to find a way to test the failure scenario for `startActivity` with implicit intent.

So I have an intent like this:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
```

And I want to test the scenario where `startActivity(intent)` will throw `ActivityNotFoundException`.

I've used `Intents.intending()` for stubbing the success scenario, but that does not have a way to test this kind of scenario.
Other option that I've tried was with a dummy Activity and creating a spy on that - but this has the big disadvantage that I need to add that activity to my Manifest (which I want to avoid).

Any ideas on how this can be tested without affecting production code?

Comment: If you have a debug build type, then you could add that activity to a debug manifest file only and thereby not affecting 'production' code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @gosr, but that won't work for me as some of the tests will also be run on production code and I need the activity to be available for testing on production code also.